# meteor iron:router Blaze.ReactiveVar calling multiple times

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I have a route I call many times. I have to subscribe two collections for having all datas, here's a snapshot:

```
var one = new Blaze.ReactiveVar(false);
var two = new Blaze.ReactiveVar(false);
this.route('stopIndex', {
  path: '/stop/:section/:stop_id',
  waitOn: function() {
      Meteor.call('getTripIdsForStop', {
        stop_id: this.params.stop_id,
        from: fromNow(),
        to: toMax(),
        db: prefix
      }, function(err, ids) {
        DEBUG && console.log('TRIP_IDS:', ids);
        Meteor.subscribe(prefix + '_trips', {
          trip_id: {$in: ids}
        }, function() {
          one.set(true);
        });
        Meteor.subscribe(prefix + '_stop_times', {
          trip_id: {$in: ids}
        }, function() {
          two.set(true);
        });
      });
      return [
        function () { return one.get(); },
        function () { return two.get(); }
      ];
    },
```

The first time I call the route, all goes fine. The second time, the `one` and `two` vars are already setted to true so the `waitOn` doesn't wait and I get a `no data` message on my template for some seconds, until collections responds. I've tried putting on the first lines of `waitOk` method:

```
one.set(false);
two.set(false);
```

but this makes the `waitOn` to wait forever. Am I doing something wrong or missing something? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this way:

```
Router.onStop(function() {
  one.set(false);
  two.set(false);
});
```

that invalidates `ReactiveVars` and will wait. I've also moved all code from `waitOn` to `data`. Now the `waitOn` is like this:

```
return [
    function () { return one.get(); },
    function () { return two.get(); }
  ];
```